# What do you call someone who ornaments the letters and pages of books

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you call someone who makes art in a book? Like beautifying the letters or putting some form of art on the sides of the pages etc.

Comment: "Garnish" is strongly associated with food, which made your question a little surreal at first glance.

Comment: I took the OP's *garnish* to mean *flourish*.

Comment: *Garnish* has another meaning too, principally concerned with deductions from pay. @Bdy I suggest changing this word in the title and body to something more appropriate: *ornament, illustrate* perhaps, or their synonyms.

Comment: There is actually a [Sweet Garnish Font](https://www.cufonfonts.com/font/sweet-garnish) used to decorate cakes!

Comment: "Here garnisher!  Come here, boy!"

Comment: Haha changed it.

Comment: Maybe you meant *gornisht*? (-:

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The decorated initial letters or marginal illustrations which can be seen in some manuscripts are called **illumination,** and those who do them are called ***illuminators.*** There's an illustration below, but it's [not simply a thing of the past](https://www.heraldicart.com/calligraphy-illumination).

From Lexico:

> [**illumination**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/illumination)
>
> 2.1 *[count noun]* An illuminated design in a manuscript.

> [**illuminate**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/illuminate)
>
> 3 Decorate (a page or letter in a manuscript) by hand with gold, silver, or coloured designs.
>
> > ‘this is a carefully written, large-format manuscript illuminated by Leonardo Bellini’

[image: Example of illumination]

Detail of a leaf from a Gradual: Initial P with the Nativity; 1495; ink, tempera and gold on vellum; each leaf: 59.8 x 4.1 cm; Cleveland Museum of Art via [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illuminated_manuscript)

Answer (score 3):

Although we usually call the person who does the artwork for a book an ***illustrator***, embellisher can be used for artwork and other flourishes, the choice/design of decorative type, etc. We can say, for example, *She embellished the book with her illustrations,* although you can embellish a book with someone else's illustrations as well.

**illustrator**

> a person who draws or creates pictures for magazines, books,
> advertising, etc. [Oxford](https://www.google.com/search?q=illustrator%20defiition&rlz=1C1CHBD_enUS911US911&oq=illustrator%20defiition&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13l3j0i13i30l6.6880j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

**embellisher**

> He who or that which beautifies or adorns. OED

> **embellish**
> To make beautiful with ornamentation : DECORATE
>
> *a book embellished with illustrations* [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embellisher)

> If something is embellished with decorative features or patterns, it
> has those features or patterns on it and they make it look more
> attractive.
>
> *The boat was embellished with carvings in red and blue*.
> *Ivy leaves embellish the front of the dresser*.  [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/embellish)

---

> ... payment of 301. to Gideon Royer, the king's writer, flourisher and
> **embellisher**, for writing, flourishing and embellishing three skins in
> vellum.. [D. P. Dukes; *Stuarts and Romanovs*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Stuarts_and_Romanovs/LaUxEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=embellisher%20flourishes&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover) p.134

> Also, he **embellished** the books with many lively sketches of scenery,
> Indians, animals, fish, canoes, and ships, along with dozens of maps
> and charts which were remarkably accurate for that day. ... [S. E. Morison; *Best
> Sellers from the U.S. Government Printing Office*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Best_Sellers/NENAXnEYxdsC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22embellished%20the%20books%20with%22&pg=PA174&printsec=frontcover).

> Comment upon the charming specimens of Fowler's skill as a book
> **embellisher** and decorator which appear in this issue of THE
> BOOKMAKER... [*American Printer and Lithographer*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Printer_and_Lithographer/SH_nAAAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=embellisher%20page&pg=PA235&printsec=frontcover).

Comment: Illustrator doesn't really work, at least if the question is about medieval-style illuminated manuscripts.  Illustrations generally have a purpose, particularly in the sort of technical works where they're most often found.  Illuminations are purely decorative.

Comment: My answer is *embellisher*. I added the definition of illustrator because the question includes art on the facing page. There was nothing in the question about medieval manuscripts. The question was edited after I answered, BTW.